# Geometric intepretation of matrix vector product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, euclidean-geometry

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0\\
    0       & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$. The task is to find a constant $c$ and a vector $v$ (not zero vector) such that $Av = cv$

My attempt is to let $v = \begin{bmatrix}
    v_1    \\
    v_2   \\ \end{bmatrix}$.

$Av=cv$ then gives

$\begin{bmatrix}
    v_1  \\
    0   \\ \end{bmatrix} = c\begin{bmatrix}
    v_1  \\
    v_2   \\ \end{bmatrix}$.

If $v_1=0$ we can have $c=0$ and $v_2 = t$ where $t \in \mathbb{R}$
yielding the zero vector.

If $v_1$ is not equal to $0$, $c$ is not zero, we must have $v_2=0$.
$v_1=c*v_1$ and $c=1$, $v_1 \in \mathbb{R}$

and we get $\begin{bmatrix}
    t  \\
    0   \\ \end{bmatrix}$.

Have I done this right? The question also states "for which choices of $c$ does such a zero-vector not exist". I'm not sure what they mean here, since it's very obvious any $c$ not equal to zero will yield a non zero $v$ if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are not both equal to zero.

I wonder if my solution is wrong, because I need to explain the geometric interpretation of what happens when I take the product $Av$ for the different $c$'s. I don't see anything special with my two answers, so I think I might not have solved it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you're on the right track. The problem really wants you to look at this in terms of $c$, so restating what you've said,

- For $c = 0$, the vector $\pmatrix{0 \\ 1}$ is a solution (as is any multiple of it).
- For $c = 1$, the vector $\pmatrix{1 \\ 0}$ is a solution (as is any multiple of it).
- For any other $c$, $Av = cv$ has no nonzero solutions (indeed, no solutions at all).

In short: you're on exactly the right track, and a little reorganizing of what you wrote gets things to be expressed the way the question-asked was probably hoping they'd be.

Comment: thank you for the help! As for the geometric interpretation of the answer; Does this mean that multiplying matrix $A$ with $v$ "transforms" it into either having a positive x-component and zero y-component or vice versa (c=1 and c=0)?

Comment: A possibly better way to think of it is that the two vectors I mentioned -- let's call them $v_1$ and $v_2$ -- both get "scaled" under multiplication by $M$. The first gets multiplied by $0$ (i.e., scaled down to nothing at all), the second gets scaled by $1$ (i.e., not changed at all). But neither one changes *direction*. In many ways, that's the simplest sort of transformation: think of stretching the $x$-axis by a factor of 2, and the y-axis by a factor of 3: that's *really* easy to understand and think about. Later in your course you'll see that many transformations are "like" this.